# Flask-SQLAlchemy InvalidRequestError: Object is already attached to session

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm creating a forum project using Flask, and managing all the users, threads, posts, etc. using Flask-SQLAlchemy. However, I've found that when I attempt to do x (e.g. edit a post), I get an InvalidRequestError if I attempt to do anything else (e.g. delete the post).

For editing a post,

```
def post_edit(id, t_id, p_id):
  post = Post.query.filter_by(id=p_id).first()
  if post.author.username == g.user.username:
    form = PostForm(body=post.body)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
      post.body = form.body.data
      db.session.commit()
      return redirect(url_for('thread', id=id, t_id=t_id))
    return render_template('post_edit.html', form=form, title='Edit')
  else:
    flash('Access denied.')
    return redirect(url_for('thread', id=id, t_id=t_id))
```

and deleting a post,

```
@app.route('/forum=<id>/thr=<t_id>/p=<p_id>/delete', methods=['GET','POST'])
def post_delete(id, t_id, p_id):
  post = Post.query.filter_by(id=p_id).first()
  if post.author.username == g.user.username:
    db.session.delete(post)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('thread', id=id, t_id=t_id))
  else:
    flash('Access denied.')
    return redirect(url_for('thread', id=id, t_id=t_id))
```

and posting a post

```
@app.route('/forum/id=<id>/thr=<t_id>', methods=['GET','POST'])
def thread(id, t_id):
  forum = Forum.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
  thread = Thread.query.filter_by(id=t_id).first()
  posts = Post.query.filter_by(thread=thread).all()
  form = PostForm()
  if form.validate_on_submit():
    post = Post(body=form.body.data,
                timestamp=datetime.utcnow(),
                thread=thread,
                author=g.user)
    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('thread', id=id, t_id=t_id))
  return render_template('thread.html', forum=forum, thread=thread, posts=posts, form=form, title=thread.title)
```

Unfortunately, the only surefire way to make this problem resolve itself is to reset the script that actually runs the app, run.py

```
#!bin/python

from app import app
app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using WooshAlchemy because it might be part of your problem. [Described here](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xvi-debugging-testing-and-profiling)

He describes the "fix" that requires modification of WooshAlchemy extension.

Usually though it could mean you called a Post model object and then attached it using "session.add" and then tried to "session.delete" or did another "session.add" on the same object.

Also your request routing is a bit strange for flask I've never seen the "thr=<t_id>" type of notation with Flask before. Has that been working well for you?

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#variable-rules

Comment: Looks like WhooshAlchemy was indeed the problem. As for the notation, it's just a shorthand for "thr=<thread_id>".

Comment: I meant the "thr=" part. But I guess you could do /thr=44/p=32/c=21 kind of url format, I just found it strange that's all. I'm glad we figured out the problem though.

Comment: That's exactly what it is; so for example, a specific thread (8) in a forum (1) creates the url "/forum/id=1/thr=8".

Answer (score 0):

I think your edit post is not done correctly. Use the populate_obj function.

```
@app.route('/forum=<id>/thr=<t_id>/p=<p_id>/edit', methods=['GET','POST'])
def post_edit(id, t_id, p_id):
    post = Post.query.filter_by(id=p_id).first()
    if post.author.username == g.user.username:
        form = PostForm(obj=post)
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            form.populate_obj(post)
            db.session.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('thread', id=id, t_id=t_id))
        return render_template('post_edit.html', form=form, title='Edit')
   else:
       flash('Access denied.')
       return redirect(url_for('thread', id=id, t_id=t_id))
```