# sqlalchemy value change doesn't commit

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following code to update some entries in a Postgres database:

```
engine = create_engine(Config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)

# Create session
Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)
s = Session()

ids_to_update = [185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 194, 195, 196, 197]

for user in models.Users.query.all():
    if user.id in ids_to_update:
        user.group = 'design_team'

s.commit()
```

but nothing happens in the database after I run this statement?
I don't get any errors from the Postgres as well?

Comment: If you have a list of values, why not use `update` with the `in_` function of sqlalchemy?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17127922/cant-delete-row-from-sqlalchemy-due-to-wrong-session, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19769841/sqlalchemy-sessions-error?rq=1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45608370/update-state-with-flask-sqlalchemy-with-postgres-will-not-commit-to-database

Comment: [You do not need to mark questions as "SOLVED" via editing the title](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/295637), or [posting updates/thanks in posts](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/109959/295637). Simply add your own answer. Anything additional can be perceived as noise for future visitors. See: [Can I answer my own question?](//stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I need to run `db.create_all()` to get the right session before  Ilja Everilä's answer worked which I took me a while to work out so thought it might be useful to post the whole final functional block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've tagged this as [flask-sqlalchemy](/questions/tagged/flask-sqlalchemy), so it is safe to say that `models.Users.query` is using the default [scoped session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/contextual.html) `db.session` to fetch those entities. You then try and commit in another session, but all the changes you've performed are actually held by `db.session`. So the fix is simple: import `db` from where you have it and instead of `s.commit()`:

```
db.session.commit()
```

But: such a simple operation could be performed as a bulk update to begin with:

```
models.Users.query.\
    filter(models.Users.id.in_(ids_to_update)).\
    update({models.Users.group: 'design_team'},
           synchronize_session=False)
# Use the correct session
db.session.commit()
```

In order to use `db` outside a request you might need a [suitable context](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/contexts/).